# Strange NStextfield drawing behaviour

Tags: macos, textfield, nstextfield

[image: Strange NStextfield behaviour]

I'm using NSTextField in OSX, why text fields used are inconsistent, Some of them are rectangle perfectly while some of them have corner ? Please see attached screenshot.

I want it to be all square perfectly. I've already checked in IB they seems to have same attributes.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: They must have different styles.

Comment: No, all of them have same style, for example when I copied position x textfield from screenshot and pasted it, it become rounded although I don't change anything?